# Enter Parameter Value on Combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I get an Enter Parameter Value from a search combo box. I have checked my spelling.

It highlights below-

Run time error 2001 on `Me.tbl_detailsubform1.Form.Requery`

Access 2010 Code:

```
Me.tbl_detailsubform1.Form.RecordSource = Task:

Function SearchCriteria()

Dim PN As String
Dim SN As String
Dim Task As String
Dim strCriteria As String

If IsNull(Me.cboProduct) Then
    PN = "[Product] like '*'"
Else
    PN = "[Product] = " & Me.cboProduct & ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboSerial) Then
    SN = "[Serial] like '*'"
Else
    SN = "[Serial] = " & Me.cboSerial & ""
End If

strCriteria = PN & " And " & SN
Task = "SELECT * FROM tbl_StockOut where " & strCriteria & " Order by PN asc"
Me.tbl_detailsubform1.Form.RecordSource = Task
Me.tbl_detailsubform1.Form.Requery

Me.Text89 = findRecordCount(Task)

If Me.Text89 = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Record Found!", vbInformation, "Search Result"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: I have attempted an edit but please confirm, or better still [edit] yourself, whether Me.tbl_detailsubform1.Form.RecordSource = Task: should be within the same code tags as the Function or if it is an indication of the line where things go wrong.

Comment: HI I did the spacing and getting The Parameter value followed by a run time error 2001. It highlights the  - Me.tbl_detailsubform1.Form.Requery

Comment: Is this in anyway related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863630/ms-access-hitting-cancel-on-query-enter-parameter-box-gives-runtime-error-2001

Comment: The error from quick Googling seems to be associated with a cancelled operation.

Comment: Yeah I had a look at that one and several others but im a learner so don't really understand that particular response? now getting a Runtime error 3061.

Comment: on which line does this occur?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445062/run-time-error-3061-too-few-parameters-expected-1-access-2007

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `[Product]` and `[Serial]` are both text fields...

Debug.Print `strCriteria` You probably need to do this:

```
If IsNull(Me.cboProduct) Then
    PN = "[Product] like '*'"
Else
    PN = "[Product] = " & Chr(34) & Me.cboProduct & Chr(34)
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboSerial) Then
    SN = "[Serial] like '*'"
Else
    SN = "[Serial] = " & Chr(34) & Me.cboSerial & Chr(34)
End If
```

Either that or the field PN doesn't exist, but your SELECT * shouldn't be causing the problem.